# A query on Galvin's theorem for bipartite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, bipartite-graphs, orientation

The Galvin's theorem is the generalized version of Dinitz conjecture that states that if the maximum degree of any bipartite graph is $\Delta$, then its edges are colorable properly if each of its edges is given a list of $\Delta$ colors to choose from.

The proof, as I have seen, is by using the fact that there exists a kernel perfect orientation of the line graph of bipartite graph. But, I have a method as follows: We know that even cycles are chromatic edge-choosable. A regular bipartite graphs consist of even cycles and possible chords (matchings). As each of the even cycle can be list edge colored with a list of exactly two colors, and the chords (matchings) can be list edge colored using a list having just one color, I think a suitable greedy list edge coloring ( by assigning a list of $\Delta$ colors to each edge) would solve the problem.

What is the defect in the method above? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You mean, a regular bipartite graph?

Comment: @FedorPetrov yes, edited

Comment: I do not yet understand the greedy procedure, would you please elaborate?

Comment: @FedorPetrov We give a list of edge of cardinality $\Delta$ to each edge. We can first remove a $1$- factor by coloring its edges using just one color from its given list. For other edges, we can color the maximal cycle of which a particular edge is part of, using just two colors from the list. Now, we remove that cycle (edges ) from the graph. We again repeat the procedure for other edges. In fact, we can say we list edge color one $2$- factor in one iteration. Repeating the process for as many $2$- factors as there are in the graph, I think we have colored all the edges.

Comment: The lists depend on edges. And after you color a 1-factor, you may loose two colors for a remaining edge, like you color $ab$ red, $cd$ blue, and you should remove the colors red and blue from the list of the edge $bc$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov ok, got it. What if the graph is $2$- factorable?

Comment: the same problem? If you remove a cycle, a remaining edge may lose 4 admissible color